# Click after filter/search on datatable returns no data

Tags: jquery, datatables, filtering

I  am using jQuery DataTables for a table that properly displays multiple (paginated) rows of data.

1. If I click on a row, I get a popup that shows the data, as desired.
2. If I page through my results, and click on a row, I get a popup that shows the data, as desired.
3. I can filter my results down by typing a name, as desired.

But if I filter my results, and then click on a row, the popup is empty of data.

Why?  Not even really sure how to debug this.

```
      ShowNewContactDialog: function () {
          egn.bwm("Loading...");
          egAjax.json('Services/foo.asmx/GetContacts',
          { 'state': objCustomer.State, 'membership': objCustomer.Member },
          function (result) {
              egn.Unblock();
              $('#ContactTable').dataTable({
                  'bJQueryUI': true,
                  'bAutoWidth': false,
                  'bDestroy': true,
                  'bServerSide': false,
                  'bProcessing': true,
                  'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
                  'aaData': result.aaData,
                  'oLanguage': {
                      'sZeroRecords': 'No records to display',
                      'sInfo': 'Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries'
                  },
                  'fnRowCallback': function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                      $(nRow).click(function () {
                          objCustomer.SelectContact(aData);
                      });
                      return nRow;
                  },
                  "aoColumns": [
                          {
                              "sTitle": "First Name",
                              "sName": "FirstName",
                              "mDataProp": "FirstName"
                          },
                          {
                              "sTitle": "Last Name",
                              "sName": "LastName",
                              "mDataProp": "LastName"
                          },
                          {
                              "sTitle": "Email Address",
                              "sName": "EmailAddress",
                              "mDataProp": "EmailAddress"
                          },
                          {
                              "sTitle": "Phone Number",
                              "sName": "BusPhone",
                              "mDataProp": "BusPhone"
                          },

                  ]
              });
              $('#btnSelectCust').hide();

              $('#ContactDialog').dialog('open');

          });
      }
```

Comment: Can you add the datatables initialisation code?

Comment: I assume `objCustomer.SelectContact(aData)` is the popup? I think you'll have to use Firebug or similar to debug that function and see what's happening.

Comment: What DataTables version are you using?

Comment: Good question. I don't know. I inherited this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

Option `fnRowCallback` that specifies callback function is not an appropriate place to attach click event handler since it's called every time when the row is drawn.

> **SOLUTION**

Remove `fnRowCallback` option and use the code below, it should work for DataTables 1.9 and 1.10.

```
$('#ContactTable').dataTable({
   // ... skipped ...
});

$('#ContactTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(){
   var data = $('#ContactTable').dataTable().fnGetData(this);
   objCustomer.SelectContact(data);
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/meq57rpr/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: I guess I don't have the right version of DataTable because I just get an error saying "on" is not supported.

Comment: @ChrisG.Williams, [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is jQuery method not DataTables, so you should have it as long as you include jQuery.